# How to create SQL Server database using Entity Framework database-first code?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

How to create a SQL Server database using Entity Framework databbase-first code?

I've mistakenly deleted the database from SQL Server, but I've added EDO in model at my VS 2017 project. So, now I've EDO code, can I restore database with the help of that code ?

Comment: Solutions like DhavalR's will restore only the basic database structure. Most of them will not re-generate things like user acounts and permissions, triggers, jobs, (because EF doesn't see them), or stored procedures, UDFs (because EF only sees their definition, not inner code), etc, and even won't re-generate any views/tables/UDTs/etc that previously existed in the database but the EF model hadn't included them (you forgot or have no need for). Obviously, re-generating the DB will also not recover any data rows. If you need to get back anything of those, look for db backups/snapshots asap.

Comment: If you have .bak file, choose "generate database from model" option from EDMX designer and restore the contents of .bak file into that DB.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl :- You are right. I am updating my answer mentioning your point. I checked what you said about sp's and all. This generates only basic db structure.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to open `edmx` in `Model Browser` in `Visual Studio`, you can generate script for database by right clicking on `edmx` diagram. Select `Generate Database from Model`.

**FYI : This will generate only basic structure. Not stored procedure, udf's etc.**

[image]

And you will get script as below.

[image]

Comment: I have updated my answer as @quetzalcoatl suggested. If you don't have `.bak` file, this is the least you can do I think.

Answer (score 0):

Exporting an Entity Data Model to a SQL-Server database

1. Open the SQL Server Management Studio.
2. Right click on Databases, select New Database
3. Type MyFirstEF on Database name. Click OK.
4. We're going to set the connection properties for your database from Visual Studio:
5. Right-click on the EDM design mode, select Generate Database from Model
6. Click on New Connection.
7. Type your SQL-Server host name on Server name field.
8. Select the database you created in Step 3 on the field Select or enter a database name. Click OK.
9. Click Next.
10. Choose a version of Entity Framework that you use . Click Next.
    You have just generated the script to create the database.
    For step by step walk-through [click here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj205424(v=vs.113).aspx)

[image]